# bootstrap method initialization exception - Opensearch RestHighLevelClient

Tags: opensearch, resthighlevelclient

**I am getting below ERROR while trying to fetch indices from opensearch**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:194)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:307)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:258)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:248)
at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:361)
at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:345)
at org.opensearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:320)
at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1918)
at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1901)
at org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1865)
at org.opensearch.client.IndicesClient.get(IndicesClient.java:768)
at com.QueriesTest.main(QueriesTest.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:254)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:328)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:127)
... 11 more

Versions:
jdk 11
`plugins { id:'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.6.RELEASE' } opensearch-java:2.6.0 opensearch-rest-high-level-client:2.9.0`

```
static RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(domainUrl, port, protocol)));

//QueriesTest.java:99
GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest(indexName); 
            GetIndexResponse response = client.indices().get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```